# Where to save data in android

Tags: android, storage, settings

I am new to android world and I have a question regarding saving the settings. I will try to explain it with an example. Let's assume we have an android app similar to gmail, where a user syncs an account with app. Where are the login/password stored so that even when powering off the phone they are still there? Are they stored in SharedPreferences, in a separate file, in database? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google and other such companies use sessions to identify a user. They do not store password in your mobile. After your first login, the server will issue a unique session ID to the user and the app may store it in SharedPreferences and after that, every consecutive server request must also send this session ID for authentication. In your case, you can very well store any settings in SharedPreferences, but storing password is not advisable. If you have a lot of data to be stored, for example you are creating a game with various features, you can use SQLite database to store and retrieve data.

**EDIT:**
Firstly, send username and password to your server using HttpUrlConnection. After this we need to extract the cookie from server response header.
The following code demonstrates on how to obtain cookie from server response:

```
                String[] tokens;
                List cookies = conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
                if (cookies != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                        String cookieString = (String) cookies.get(i);
                        tokens = cookieString.split(";");
                        List<String> cookieHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String str : tokens) {
                            if (str.contains("httponly")||str.contains("HttpOnly")) {
                                str = str.trim();
                                cookieHeaders.add(str);
                            } else {
                                Log.d("loginactivity","str "+str);
                                str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("=")).trim();
                                cookieHeaders.add(str);
                            }
                        }
                        String token = cookieString;
                    }
                }
```

You can the put the token in shared preferences:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("token", token).apply();
```

After this, add cookie to any consecutive requests to server.

```
String cookie = sharedPreferences.getString("token","");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie",cookie);
```

Comment: I need to provide an authorization feature to my app as well. I can definitely send a session token to the app. Can you provide me with more information on that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can save data on SQLite database. Your app will need access to file system permission.